# how make space between buttons zero?

Tags: xamarin, stacklayout

I have this in xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:project"
         x:Class="project.MainPage">


<StackLayout Padding="0,0,0,15" Spacing="0"> <!-- multiple things in a    page -->

    <Button Text="first" HorizontalOptions="Center"  VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>

    <Label Text="title" 
       VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
       HorizontalOptions="Center" />

        <!--<Entry Text="Registrarse"  VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
       HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
    <Entry Text="Iniciar Sesion"
       HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Start"/>-->


    <Button Text="Registrarse" HorizontalOptions="Center"  VerticalOptions="Center" Margin="0,0,0,0" />
    <Button Text="Iniciar Sesion" HorizontalOptions="Center"  VerticalOptions="Center" Margin="0,0,0,0" />

</StackLayout>
```

I want to know why the the buttons always are separated vertically and aren't one above the other

Comment: For both buttons, try setting `VerticalOptions="Start"`. If that doesn't work, try setting the first to `Start` and the second to `StartAndExpand`

Comment: it didn't work :(

Comment: Is the issue on Android, iOS, or both?

Comment: I am only checking in android, but if I put negative spacing it starts to look like I want it

Comment: @GuillermoGómezSánchez is right, setting negative margin will help you get rid of additional spacing. May be the additional spacing is due to the ViewGroup padding in the native layout renderers

Comment: thanks both for the help :)